# When using ABAC security, how do you look up rules?

Tags: xacml, abac

When implementing ABAC/XACML, the spec indicates you should intercept requests for sensitive data with PEPs, which route the request to PDPs (the PEPs include attributes about the subject, environment, resource and action when calling the PDP).

The PDP then determines what rules need to be evaluated for an access decision.

From Wikipedia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML

> XACML provides a target,[5] which is basically a set of simpliﬁed conditions for the subject, resource, and action that must be met for a policy set, policy, or rule to apply to a given request. Once a policy or policy set is found to apply to a given request, its rules are evaluated to determine the access decision and response.
>
> Policy set, policy and rule can all contain target elements.

It's my understanding that how the PDP decides what rules in the PIP are applicable is implementation specific, but this seems like a very important part of the process-- if you miss a rule, for instance, you would not evaluate the request properly. What ways have folks implemented this? What's worked and what hasn't?  (I'm reluctantly leaning towards lookups against an EAV-ish table.)

Comment: I've updated the Wikipedia page to give a better explanation of the XACML architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always configure a PDP with a set of policies. You can give the PDP any number of policies and policy sets (groups of policies) ***but*** you must specify the entry point, i.e. there must be a root policy. That root policy may then contain and / or link to other policies (or policy sets).

The PDP alone decides which policies to invoke and evaluate based on the incoming request from the PEP. The PEP does not know how many policies there are. You would not miss a rule like you state in your question. It is the PDP's responsibility not to. You would not typically implement your own PDP. You would use an off-the-shelf one. There are several open-source engines e.g. SunXACML and commercial alternatives e.g. Axiomatics.

The PIP is used for attribute value retrieval, not for policy retrieval.

[image: Sample Representation of a XACML policy]

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. But how does a PDP decide what policies need to be evaluated? Something like, if the request is for a 'write' action, evaluate all policies that include might allow for write actions?

Comment: Policies contain targets which determine whether they apply. For instance a policy target might say role == manager. When the PEP sends the PDP a request, it contains attribute values that are used to determine whether the policy is applicable

Comment: OK, thanks. Let's say the PDP finds a few applicable policies (based on attributes passed by the PEP), and determines it needs to look up some more attributes, does the PDP then look more required policies based on the attributes it just looked up. (Not sure this has much 'real word' relevance.. )

Comment: The PDP would look up attributes from the PIP on the fly as need be (this is actually implementation-specific so different PDPs behave differently)